# Find the longest string duality

Tags: algorithm

`T1`:
Find the length of longest substring T that contains at most k distinct characters.

`T2`: 
Find the length of shortest substring T contains at least k distinct characters.

Is `T1` a strong or weak duality of `T2`? Essentially, are `T1` and `T2` asking the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I would answer both questions with a no. Consider the example string:

```
"This is an example. Don't ask me about the example string."
```

For k=15 gives `"'t ask me about the example st"` for T1 and `"xample. Don't ask"` for T2.

These were computed using the following Python program:

```
1 'T' 'T'
2 't t' 'Th'
3 'is is ' 'Thi'
4 'his is ' 'This'
5 'is is an ' 'This '
6 'his is an ' 'n exam'
7 'is is an exa' 'n examp'
8 'his is an exa' 'n exampl'
9 ' me about the e' 'xample. D'
10 ' me about the exam' 'xample. Do'
11 't ask me about the e' 'xample. Don'
12 't ask me about the exam' "xample. Don'"
13 "'t ask me about the exam" "xample. Don't"
14 't ask me about the example st' 'xample string.'
15 "'t ask me about the example st" "xample. Don't ask"
16 "is is an example. Don't ask me a" "ple. Don't ask me abou"
17 "is is an example. Don't ask me abo" 'bout the example string'
18 "s an example. Don't ask me about the example st" 'bout the example string.'
19 "his is an example. Don't ask me about the example st" 'k me about the example string.'
x = "This is an example. Don't ask me about the example string."

def factors(s):
    return [s[i:j] for i in range(len(s)+1) for j in range(i, len(s)+1)]

for k in range(20):
    t1 = max([f for f in factors(x) if len(set(f)) <= k], key=len)
    t2 = min([f for f in factors(x) if len(set(f)) >= k], key=len)

    print k, repr(t1), repr(t2)
```

Which prints:

```
0 '' ''
1 'T' 'T'
2 't t' 'Th'
3 'is is ' 'Thi'
4 'his is ' 'This'
5 'is is an ' 'This '
6 'his is an ' 'n exam'
7 'is is an exa' 'n examp'
8 'his is an exa' 'n exampl'
9 ' me about the e' 'xample. D'
10 ' me about the exam' 'xample. Do'
11 't ask me about the e' 'xample. Don'
12 't ask me about the exam' "xample. Don'"
13 "'t ask me about the exam" "xample. Don't"
14 't ask me about the example st' 'xample string.'
15 "'t ask me about the example st" "xample. Don't ask"
16 "is is an example. Don't ask me a" "ple. Don't ask me abou"
17 "is is an example. Don't ask me abo" 'bout the example string'
18 "s an example. Don't ask me about the example st" 'bout the example string.'
19 "his is an example. Don't ask me about the example st" 'k me about the example string.'
```

Comment: For k=15 gives `"''t ask me about the example st" "xample. Don't ask ""`for T1 and `""'t ask me about the example st" "xample. Don't ask""` for T2. Both are the same?

Comment: I didn't think I need to explain the program output. The format is k, output for T1, output for T2.